# Choose model for time series forecasting with R

Tags: r

I try to forecast my web visitors on the web site for 10 future days using time series.
I have used a `auto.arima()` model My time series is daily.

How can I choose between `ets()` model and `auto.arima()` model concidering that:

```
accuracy(auto.arima)

                   ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE    MAPE MASE      ACF1
Training set 26.84448 877.9984 697.2491 -0.7432541 9.72338  NaN -0.126274
```

and

```
accuracy(ets)

                   ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE MASE       ACF1
Training set 10.38619 1039.264 833.8032 -1.01747 11.62925  NaN 0.02922446
```

Comment: i have tried to find the response but no solution thanks..

Comment: You can choose the best model based on lower MAPE value.

Comment: @Gaurav, why shoudh i choose ets model ?

Comment: @Sidhha, can you explaine me the meaning of MPAE

Comment: Becoz of lower RMSE and MAPE values for ets

Comment: @Gaurav, so i choose the auto.arima and not ets model

Comment: Yeah sorry auto.arima. The question earlier was not formatted so I saw 26.84448 under the RMSE header for auto.arima

Comment: @Gaurav, thanks did you know how can i export my predict output into excel file like this(3columns): Date pred  se consedering that my output is $pred
Time Series:
Start = c(2015, 1) 
End = c(2015, 5) 
Frequency = 365 
[1] 5659.850 6425.983 7778.235 8749.321 8851.684

$se
Time Series:
Start = c(2015, 1) 
End = c(2015, 5) 
Frequency = 365 
[1]  879.2036 1079.9762 1115.6224 1117.8931 1121.6338

Answer (score 2):

You should use *forecast* and not *predict* to forecast your web visitors.
Here an example based on simulated data (I have no access to your data).
You may adapt this example to your data. Hope this may be of help.

#### Time series with daily data

Data simulation

```
data <- rnorm(3650, m=10, sd=2)
```

Use ts() to create time series

```
series <- ts(data, frequency=365, start=c(1919, 1))

attributes(series)
class(series)
length(series)
```

Plot the data

```
plot(series, col ="aquamarine")
```

The accuracy of forecasts can only be determined by considering how well a model performs on new data that were not used when fitting the model.
The size of the test set is typically about 20% of the total sample

Training set

Use data from 1919 to 1926 for forecasting

```
sr = window(series, start=c(1919,1), end=c(1926,365))
```

Test set

Use remaining data from 1927 to 1928 to test accuracy

```
ser = window(series, start=c(1927,1), end=c(1928, 365))
```

Herewith enclosed is an exercise I've done on the basis of the online book of Hyndman and Athanasopoulos: "Forecasting: principles and practice", a very good reading.You may find the book here: https://www.otexts.org/fpp

Since this is a very simply simulation, there is no real trend in it, so the two models produce similar forecasting of a linera trend. Your data in all likelihood will have a seasonal component.

---

### Assign the data to a vector of convenience

```
trainData <- sr     ### Training set (8 years, daily data)
testData <- ser     ### Test set    (2 years, daily data)
```

---

### Auto-arima without stepwise (more precise)

```
library(fpp)
```

The default value in auto.arima() is test="kpss". 
A KPSS test has a null hypothesis of stationarity
In general, all the defaults are set to the values that give the best forecasts on average.

Caution, takes a while to compute

```
arimaMod <- auto.arima(trainData, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)
arimaMod.Fr <-forecast(arimaMod,h=730)      ### h is the length of the forecast, in this case 2 years = 365*2
```

Plot of the prediction and the test set

```
plot(arimaMod.Fr, plot.conf=FALSE)
lines(testData, col="red")
legend("topleft",lty=1,bty = "n",col=c("red","blue"),c("testData","ARIMAPred"))
```

---

### Only the prediction

Plot the test set

```
plot(ser, main="Daily data", ylab="", xlab="Months", col = "red")
```

Plot the forecast on the training set

```
lines(arimaMod.Fr$mean, col="blue", lwd=3)
```

---

### Accuracy

Accuracy for forecasting of sr (forecasted data) on ser (original data used as test set)
The best model had the lowest error (particularly the MAPE, Mean absolute percentage error)

```
accuracy(arimaMod.Fr,testData)
```

---

### Test residues of arima

```
tsdisplay(residuals(arimaMod))
```

---

### ETS

```
fit.ets <- ets(trainData)

fr.ets <- forecast(fit.ets,h=730)

plot(forecast(fit.ets,h=730))
```

Compare accuracy of ETS vs ARIMA
There is an overlap between the ETS and the ARIMA forecasting,
So I've plotted the ETS forecasting with a wider line

```
plot(testData)

lines(fr.ets$mean, col="red", lwd=5)
    lines(arimaMod.Fr$mean, col="green")
legend("topleft",lty=1,cex=1,y.intersp=0.6,bty = "n",col=c("black","red","green"),c("data","ETS","ARIMA"))
```

Accuracy test

```
accuracy(fr.ets,testData)
accuracy(arimaMod.Fr,testData)
```

Comment: hello and thank you very much for sharing your knowldge,i just have a question, for information i have a daily data witch containe 2 columns date and numbre of visitor 's site.my data from 01/6/2011 to 24/08/2015.(how can i send you or show you my data ).according to these information can i use the same script like you ?

Comment: i have used the same script but i have always the same value predected! why? i have write this arimaMod.Fr <-forecast(arimaMod,h=365) but always the same value predected by the arimaMod

Comment: I think you need to rearrange your data.   A time series is a sequence of measurements made over a time interval. So, your first column is the "time interval", and the number of visitors is your "measurement".   Essentially, you should have a sequence of measurements for each day of the year, form January 1st to December 31th.    When there was no visitor, your measurement is 0.

Comment: At the end, your should have a sequence of 365 measurements, a column with values that may go from 0 (no visitors) to any number your site had registered.   At this point your must create a ts object, as indicated, then plot your data to see whether there is any trend: no trend, no forecast.

Comment: thanks , so i can not use data for 01/06/2011 until 23/08/2015 ? or must i remplace missing value by zero ? another question how can I test the presence of trend in my time sereis using R? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best model is the model with the the lowest error (particularly the MAPE, Mean absolute percentage error).

However, the accuracy of forecasts can only be determined by considering how well a model performs on new data that were not used when fitting the model.

The size of the test set is typically about 20% of the total sample.

So, you need to split the series in a training set and a test set.

You may consult this tutorial, which is based on the online book of Hyndman and Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: principles and practice", a very good reading. The book explains with details what MAPE and the other measures of error are.
You may find the book here: https://www.otexts.org/fpp

The tutorial is here: https://rpubs.com/RatherBit/90267

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: ,thank you very much,  in my case i have a daily time series (frequecy=365) so this my R code myts <- ts(inputData$visites, frequency=335, start=c(2014, 1)) arimaOut <- auto.arima(myts)
predicteds <- predict(arimaOut, 30)
accuracy(arimaOut)  accuracy(auto.arima)

                   ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE    MAPE MASE      ACF1
Training set 26.84448 877.9984 697.2491 -0.7432541 9.72338  NaN -0.126274  is this true ? thanks

Comment: frequency should be 365 not 335 (a typo?)    You should split the series in a training set and a test set and use the 'forecast' command to get what you want.    Some of the error measures will turn to be NaN, since they are specific to some models and are not valid for other models.

Comment: yes sorry , its is an error,for information, my data contain 2           columns date visites
1 2014-01-01    3114
2 2014-01-02    5954
3 2014-01-03    5342
4 2014-01-04    4929
5 2014-01-05    5633
6 2014-01-06    5890 this my  R code:myts <- ts(inputData$visites[1:335], frequency=365, start=c(2014, 1)) arimaOut <- auto.arima(myts)
predicteds <- predict(arimaOut, 30) is it true now ? thanks

Comment: any help please ?